# For a Spring webapp with pure Java config, does it make sense to have 2 distinct contexts?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I am new to Spring Java config, and was wondering something.

Traditionnally Spring webapps have had 2 different contexts, the root application context and the dispatcher servlet context. The root context contains basically everything up to the service layer (persistence configuration like JPA and data access layer) and the servlet context containing all MVC and other web-related things.

The web context inherits from the root context, so web components have access to beans in the root context but not the opposite.

With a modern approach using XML-less config and a `org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer`, does it still make sense to have 2 different contexts ?

It would seem simpler to just have a few annotated `@Configuration` classes regrouping beans by layer (e.g. one for data access layer, one for service layer, one for web layer) and load all of them in the same context, like this :

```
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServletContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherServletContext.register(MyPersistenceConfig.class, MyServicesConfig.class, MyMvcConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServletContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

However I have seen examples where a root context is still created, and its lifecycle managed using a `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` like this :

```
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {

        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(MyPersistenceConfig.class, MyServicesConfig.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServletContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherServletContext.register(MyMvcConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServletContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

For a simple webapp (single maven module), does the second approach bring any concrete benefits that balance the extra complexity ? What is the best practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for advices, but it is not far from opinions. This answer is what **I** have understood of Spring philosophia.

Spring *allows* to use different contextes for the non MVC part and the MVC part and *advises* to do so, because separation of concerns (*) is considered as good practice. It never force developper to do it.

You *can* put everything in a single context in java configuration, exactly the same you can do it with XML

It is up to you to know if that pseudo-rule (2 contextes) is relevant for your application. If you later could move from Spring MVC to another framework, it **is** relevant. If you are working in a large organization where different developpers could work on the MVC part and on the non MVC part, it **is** relevant. If it is a really simple application, with one single developper, and little expected evolutions, you can certainly exchange *best practices* against simplicity.

Rules are only guidelines, and developpers must know when they must be followed, and when they can be ignored. And it really depends on the general context, size of project, of organization and general experience.

(*) separating the Model part (service and persistence) from the VC part (user interface) is considered good because :

- you can (in theory) change the UI part while keeping the model part (migration from a traditionnal WebApp to a fat client is just changing the UI to a minimal RESTfull interface)
- you can develop and test the different layers with as little adherence possible
- you can have different teams on Model and ViewController parts with neat separation of responsabilities
- it may be enforced by corporate rules

Comment: Thank you Serge for the general answer. But I was hoping for something more like a list of specific advantages that can be gained from having separate contexts, for example I can think of "You can build unit tests for your service layer independently of the web framework" or, like you mentioned, "you could more easily switch web framewok in the future". If you edit your question in that style I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

1) One context per app may become just another reincarnation of Singleton anti-pattern. Basically it's single scope for your stuff and when you have many beans, especially ambiguous dependencies, it quickly leads to problems.

2) You can do lot of fancy stuff with building and destroying child contexts in real-time on demand, thus having less care about long-lived objects, event hierarchies etc. (though not something you would need for simple webapps)